# Why do Double.parseDouble(null) and Integer.parseInt(null) throw different exceptions?

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception, numberformatexception

Why do Double.parseDouble(null) and Integer.parseInt(null) throw different exceptions?

Is this a historical accident or intentional? The documentation clearly states two types of exceptions for [`Double.parseDouble(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29) and one for [`Integer.parseInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29), but it seems inconsistent:

```
Integer.parseInt(null); // throws java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
```

However

```
Double.parseDouble(null); // throws java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: @Aquillo: There is `double` primitive http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: Checking the source code of the respective methods, it seems like just an inconsistency. `parseDouble` does not do a null check, and just throws an NPE when it is encountered, but in `parseInt`, then input string is checked for `null`. I can't see any good reason why they should behave different.

Comment: I have checked that they throw the sameNumberFormatException.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

> It is reasonable to expect the same exceptions to be thrown for null; however, these api's are very old and may not be able to be changed at this point.

And:

> Since the exception behavior is long-standing and specified in the JavaDoc, it is impractical to change either method's behavior at this time.  Closing as will not fix.

As taken from: [Bug Report: Integer.parseInt() and Double.parseDouble() throw different exceptions on null.](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4787924)

Like others have stated: It's likely made by different authors.

Comment: Related and interesting bug report: http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6463998 Seems like in Java 6, parse method from Double/Float class throws NPE.

Comment: Amusingly, the comment said that this functionality was "very old" *at the time,* and that was 15 years ago now.

Comment: This inconsistency most likely originates in Java 1.0.  Unfortunately, it would be difficult to verify that.  I don't think Java 1.0 is available for download, and you would need a Windows 95 / NT box to run it.  Or an ancient SPARC machine.)

Answer (score 59):

**Note: everything in this post is in the source of Java7-b147**

`Double.parseDouble()` goes into a Sun library (in [`sun.misc.FloatingDecimal`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/sun/misc/FloatingDecimal.java#FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString%28java.lang.String%29)) the first important thing that happens is:

```
in = in.trim(); // don't fool around with white space.
                // throws NullPointerException if null
```

`Integer.parseInt()` is done manually in the [`Integer`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/Integer.java#Integer.parseInt%28java.lang.String%2Cint%29) class. The first important thing that happens is:

```
if (s == null) {
    throw new NumberFormatException("null");
}
```

I would guess there are two different authors.