# Difference in behaviour between Double.parseDouble and Integer.parseInt

Tags: java

It seems parseDouble can accept strings with trailing spaces, but parseInt and parseLong throw an Exception.

e.g. For this test case

```
@Test
public void testNumberParsing() {
    try {
        Double.parseDouble("123.0 ");
        System.out.println("works");
    }catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("does not work");
    }
    try {
        Integer.parseInt("123 ");
        System.out.println("works");
    }catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("does not work");
    }
    try {
        Long.parseLong("123 ");
        System.out.println("works");
    }catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("does not work");
    }
}
```

The results are

```
works
does not work
does not work
```

Why the difference in behaviour? Is that intentional?

Comment: The only answer in the linked duplicate only discusses the implementation of these methods, without even mentioning that this behavior is also documented in [the JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16324831/2513200

Comment: In short, it's history - `Integer.parseInt` existed from the very beginning, `Double.parseDouble` was added in 1.2 according to the JavaDocs. Digging out the reasons behind the decisions would require some Mailing List Archeology, I suppose. They were never changed due to backwards-compatibility considerations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This behaviour is actually documented (though this is quite a bad design...)!

[`Double.parseDouble`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble-java.lang.String-):

> Returns a new double initialized to the value represented by the specified String, as performed by the valueOf method of class Double.

[`Double.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-):

> Leading and trailing whitespace characters in s are ignored. Whitespace is removed as if by the String.trim() method; that is, both ASCII space and control characters are removed.

[`Integer.parseInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-int-):

> The characters in the string **must all be decimal digits**, except that the first character may be an ASCII minus sign '-' ('\u002D') to indicate a negative value or an ASCII plus sign '+' ('\u002B') to indicate a positive value.

Comment: Documented but incoherent.

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy Yeah, I suppose that's true.

Answer (score 1):

From the source code of [parseDouble](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/misc/FloatingDecimal.java#FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString%28java.lang.String%29)

```
  in = in.trim(); // don't fool around with white space.
```

However this is not happening in case of `parseInt`.  They are simply checking for `null` and proceeding further.

Agree with you. Authors should have done the same for [Integer](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Integer.java#Integer.parseInt%28java.lang.String%2Cint%29) as well.

Comment: Or the opposite :)

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy Hopefully in the next version ;)

Comment: @ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ it is extremely unlikely that the behavior of either of these methods will ever be changed - they have been around for a very long time, and the behavior is documented, thus part of the method's contract and can be relied on.

Comment: @Hulk Exactly. We have no option but just go with them.

Answer (score 0):

Not the same authors I suppose, thus incoherent from a Java API point of view.
One guy thinks you have to deal with trimming yourself, while the other one thinks the method can do it for you.
I am not sure which one I prefer, sometimes the stricter code (less lax) can be better.